# How to add Payment Gateway Integration in React Native?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, payment-gateway

I'm using [Atom Payment Gateway](https://www.atomtech.in/) integration in React Native App.

For that I'm using a `WebView` component to redirect from my App to payment website by passing the dynamic url to WebView component.

How can I get the response from the API after success or failure of payment?
Or Can I do integration without using webview?